# Symfony, how can I make the credential from an in_memory provider private in a public code base?

Tags: php, symfony, github, open-source, symfony-security

I setup a Symfony project to use some credential from an in_memory provider:

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user1:
                    password: password1
                    roles: 'ROLE1'
```

Now the code for this application is going to be released on github and I obviously want to keep the credentials private.

Is there a way to load this configurations from a different (non-versioned) file? I'm looking for a solution that allows me to edit the code as little as possible and, if possible, to avoid changing the security provider used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your password as Parameter

In your `security.yml` :

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                user1:
                    password: "%your_parameter_key%"
                    roles: 'ROLE1'
```

In your `parameters.yml` :

```
parameters:
    your_parameter_key: your_secret_password
```

Usually, `parameters.yml` should be ignored by GIT.

Comment: And that's it! Thank you very much.